# How to use stencilFunc function in Three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js

Can I use stencilFunc and stencilOp functions in Three.js?
I tried to implement code for stencil test, but didn't work.

```
var scene = new THREE.Scene();
var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
    antialias: true,
    stencil: true
});

function render() {
    var context = renderer.context;

    context.enable(context.STENCIL_TEST);
    context.stencilFunc(context.ALWAYS, 0, 0xffffffff);
    context.stencilOp(context.REPLACE, context.REPLACE, context.REPLACE);
    context.clearStencil(0);
    context.clear(context.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT, context.DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT, context.STENCIL_BUFFER_BIT);

    renderer.render(scene, camera);
    context.stencilFunc(context.EQUAL, 1, 0xffffffff);
    context.stencilOp(context.KEEP, context.KEEP, context.KEEP);

    context.disable(context.STENCIL_TEST);
    context.flush();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you create WebGL renderer, by default it will be true, as per the threeJS documentation

[http://threejs.org/docs/#Reference/Renderers/WebGLRenderer](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/src/renderers/WebGLRenderer.js)

You can directly call clearStencil(), from the rendered object, since its the behaviour of the renderer, Not sure why you want to call it from context, Also

some of the functions that you are calling in the code does not exists in the ThreeJs webGL renderer class.

Below is the link to the class source Code . Please check

https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/src/renderers/WebGLRenderer.js